# How can we determine the equation of motion of a specific SHM with initial displacement and velocity specified?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

To explain my query, let's consider the following situation:

> A particle is performing SHM on the $x$-axis with the origin as its mean position. At $t=0 $, the particle is on the positive side of $x$ axis, $\frac{A}{2}$ distance away from the origin (where $A$ is the amplitude) and is travelling **towards** the origin.

---

Here is what I did:

I started by assuming the general equation as:  $x=Asin(\omega t+\phi)$ where $\omega$ is the angular frequency and $\phi$ is the initial phase constant.  Since the particle's displacement is $\frac{A}{2}$ at t=0, putting in the values, we get $sin(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}$

This is where I started having problems. There are multiple options for choosing the value of $\phi$ : $\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{5\pi}{6}$ but then we also have to take care of the fact that velocity must be negative at t=0 so we would have to apply these conditions to the first derivative equation of $x$ and I'm a bit confused on how to proceed.

---

For reference, I'm going to mention the equation that's given in my book for this situation so that if someone wants to, they can explain this to me with reference to that.

> $x=-Asin(\frac{2\pi t}{T}-\frac{\pi}{6})$ (here, they've simply substituted $\omega=\frac{2\pi t}{T}$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you did, Start by considering the general solution
$$x(t)=A\cos (\omega t+\phi)$$
Putting the initial conditions
$$x(0)=\frac{A}{2}=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)\Rightarrow \cos(\phi)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Further the velocity of the particle
$$v(t)=-A\omega \cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
$$v(0)=-A\omega \cos(\phi)<0\Rightarrow \phi=\frac{\pi}{3}$$
So the final equation of motion becomes
$$x(t)=A\cos\left(\omega t+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$$